Unable to access Keycloak admin console due to 'Timeout when waiting for 3rd party check iframe message' error
I'm having trouble accessing the admin console of my Keycloak application deployed on Scalingo. When I attempt to log in, I encounter the following error:
Blocked loading mixed active content “http://my-app/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/3p-cookies/step1.html”
Uncaught Object { error: "Timeout when waiting for 3rd party check iframe message." } 
I have tried the following steps to resolve the issue, but they have not been successful:

Attempting to change the environment variables in Scalingo related to Keycloak's configuration, but this did not resolve the issue.

I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue so that I can access the Keycloak admin console. Please let me know if you need any additional information.
Thank you for your help.
